# Audio editor that can add an echo effect

Tags: sound, editor

I want to know which is the best audio editor for Linux based operating systems because I have many religious poems which are to be edited and enhanced with echo.

Can anyone suggest me an audio editor that can add such an echo effect?

Comment: "audacity" is the name. It is in the repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Audacity is the powerful audio editor and it is available in Ubuntu Software Center. It is not very user friendly and intuitive as for today standards, but definitely will do the job.

Official documentation is good starting point; it contains manuals, tutorials and usage tips:

[Audacity  Help](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/help/)

Regarding to your question, the crucial section is:

[Reverb Section of Audacity Manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEoQFjAD&url=http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/reverb.html&ei=__eFU46HFc-3yAS-9YHgCw&usg=AFQjCNEfWMrmn-ztUJkMLlNK9-hshNU4Dg&sig2=Q_cdhPwkmygK98sq6NeCYg&bvm=bv.67720277,d.aWw)

You may also find helpful:

[Youtube echo/reverb walkthrough](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCI6R0mnlS4&ei=__eFU46HFc-3yAS-9YHgCw&usg=AFQjCNHYkRUNree4E1dj_NA_Q5QoHCxvxQ&sig2=gwMGuwgC19CMYQ8InF6CPA&bvm=bv.67720277,d.aWw)

Comment: can i get another one as it is not too handy

Comment: @agharehanabbas I'm afraid that you will not find anything better than Audacity.

Comment: so can you give me any link for its tutorials

Comment: @agharehanabbas Sure, I added a link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not happy with audacity and are willing to dive deeper into audio, I recommend [ardour](https://ardour.org/). It's a DAW (digital audio workstation) and will therefore be able to do much more than you probably need, but if you want to produce audio in a really professional quality, knowing how to work with Ardour will make your life much easier.
For your use case, it is as simple as recording on a new track in Ardour and then dropping one of the reverb/delay plugins in there and tweaking the parameters.

Comment: I need an audio editor that can edit .wav files. My editing task is simply to cut 2-3 minutes of silence from the end of a .wav file. Is it possible to do this in Ardour? Audacity can do this easily for all of the audio formats that I have tried except for the .wav format.

Comment: You can import your .wav, cut it as you please and export to .wav again, so yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

`sox` is a command-line tool that does this. Check out the documentation here and search for "reverb":

http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html